# Test if Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 (and later) is installed on client

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have inherited an old Windows forms application which is (among other things) using Crystal reports to produce PDF:s for printing. I'm trying to make it use `Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010` components instead of older versions of the same but I'm having problems checking if the required version is installed on the client computer. I want the application to work even if Crystal is not installed, with the exception of PDF generation of course.

The application does something similar to this (irrelevant details excluded):

```
try {
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

    //do something with the report, produce pdf etc
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.Write(e);
    throw();
}
```

The exception is then caught again in the calling form which in turn shows some info including a link to download the correct Crystal installation files.

I assume this has been working before, but after I have updated to Crystal components 13.#.#.# this is no longer enough. The `ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();` triggers a `System.TypeInitializationException` leaving `report` as null. So there is nothing that I can subsequently dispose. However, *something* gets created, because a while later, the `Finalizer` runs, causing another `System.TypeInitializationException` to be thrown which in turn causes the application to crash.

How can I test if Crystal is installed prior to running `new ReportDocument();` in a way that will not cause a subsequent exception on the Finalizer thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to load the Type using Reflection. This should prevent the need to instantiate but will allow you to verify the Type can be created.

Comment: Thanks, please check my own answer below, and in particular the disclaimer on the bottom. Comments?

Comment: Your solution is fine. I'd personally have a list of the referenced assemblies (you can get through using a disassembler or the native .net framework ILDASM tool) of the crystal object you are trying to create and do a Reflection load on a class in each of the known dependent assemblies - this will also trap a partial installation of Crystal (which happens distressingly often). Otherwise - no problem with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to accept answer by @PhillipH since he pointed me in the direction of reflection. But I still want to show what I actually did.

The exception that I was getting on the `ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();` line was saying (among other things):

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So in order to test, I added this:

```
            System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304");
```

before newing up the `ReportDocument`. When Crystal is not installed, this throws, the calling form will catch it and display the "Here's how to download and install Crystal" form.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not used to working with `Reflection` so I cannot really say if this is good or completely boneheaded. Seems to work though, no `Finalizer` errors after the change.

Answer (score 0):

I simply check for the assembly path:

```
If Not Directory.Exists(" C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine") Then
        InstallCrystalRuntime()
     End If
```